# How do I take words from one text file out of another? Python

Tags: python, file

```
tran = open("rep-small.txt")
stop = open("stopSQL.txt")
cTran = open("cleanTran.txt.","w")

badList = []
for line in stop:
    badList.append(line)

def cleantxt():
    for line in tran:
        for word in badList:
            line = line.replace(word,"")
        cTran.write(line)
```

It is writing cTran.txt but it isn't taking out the words from stop.
the stop file is formatted this way:

a

and

the

it

with each word on a different line.

Comment: These question have so many mistakes. What's in your tran.txt at the first

Comment: it is a transcript from a debate. I want to count the relevant words in it eventually, but right now I need to take out the words that don't matter to me like: a, the, it, and.

Answer (score 0):

You can just skip the for loop:
(Btw are you calling the function cleantxt()?)

```
tran = open("rep-small.txt")

cTran = open("cleanTran.txt.","w")

def cleantxt():
    for line in tran.readlines():
        for word in badList:
            line = line.replace(word,"")
        cTran.write(line)
    ctran.close()

with open("stopSQL.txt") as stop: # The With-Statement calls the close() function after its finished executing
    badList = stop.readlines() # Add lines to list

cleantxt()
```

Comment: yes, my function is cleantxt(), I will me using it within another function later.

Comment: I'm calling it in shell and it doesn't do anything

Comment: `line = line.replace(word.rstrip(), '')`, and you forgot to call the `cleantxt` method.

Answer (score -1):

You never read "stop" as the lines, try

```
for line in stop.readlines():
```